# Ni particle in complex sentence

Tags: grammar

暴力に正当な理由があるとすれば、自分や誰かを危険から守るためだけだ。  in this sentence why did we use に particle after 暴力. how does it come here, explain the grammar

Answer (score 1):

That is a complex sentence, but actually, only the first part is relevant.

Maybe the size of the sentence is a little distracting.

> 「暴力に正当な理由がある」
>
> 「ぼうりょくにせいとうなりゆうがある」
>
> There is a justified reason for the violence.

Basically, に is there because of ある。

I googled 理由がある。

> A book on Amazon...
>
> 不愉快なことには理由がある
>
> A book defending jazz...
>
> すごいジャズには理由（ワケ）がある
>
> An page about energy bars...
>
> その栄養には、理由がある。

It's kind of like English.

"There's a reason to..." or "There's a reason in..."

You can read more about に and the verbs that like it at [this question.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%A7-revisited)

Comment: Oh, maybe I meant [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60/particles-%e3%81%ab-vs-%e3%81%a7?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [this question...](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8229/using-%e3%81%a7-instead-of-%e3%81%ab-with-%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b?rq=1)

Comment: is ni particle working here as FOR meaning.??

Comment: No, it's used mark the scope of existence of something when followed by ...いる/ある, in this case, the existence of a justfication

Comment: But while i am reading a sentence having に in it, I cant think it of as a existence..My mind goes into direction as に. any better way to remember it ??